# Partitioning the set of Pauli words into abelian pieces

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, quantum-mechanics

Let $\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z$ be the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). A *Pauli word* of length $n$ is defined as the tensor product $\otimes_{i=1}^n\sigma_i$ of operators $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n\in\{\mathbf 1,\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z\}$. The set $PW_n$ of Pauli words of length $n$ has cardinality $4^n$. A subset $A\subset PW_n$ is called *abelian* if $u\circ v=v\circ u$ for any $u,v\in A$.

> **Question.** What is the number of partitions of the set $PW_n\setminus \{\otimes_{i=1}^n\mathbf 1\}$ into $2^n+1$ abelian subsets $A_{1},\dots,A_{2^n+1}$ of cardinality $|A_i|=2^n-1$?

---

This problem was posed in December 2019 by a Francis Drake (probably, a pseudo) on page [41](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=3&page=41) of [Volume 3](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=3) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/view.php).

Comment: I think that your project is very good, I would like to see more notebooks containing problems from other groups/departments of mathematics in this website. Yours is a very good idea. Isn't required a response to this comment.